# Node missing ) after argument list

Tags: node.js

Its probably a stupid mistake, but its taking me too long to find the answer

When i run this simple program (node index.js) i get an error:

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list (line 55)

You can see sublimelinter found nothing either

I've tried to delete and install all packages again

I've triple checked everything

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var fs = require('fs');
var readLine = require('readline');

var URL_SEED= "https://g1.globo.com/";
var MAX_PAGES_TO_VISIT = 100;

var pagesVisited = []; //array, {objeto}
var numPagesVisited = 0;
var pagesToVisit = [];
var allAbsoluteLinks = [];
var url = new URL(URL_SEED); //pesq
var urlBase = url.protocol + "//" + url.hostname; //pesq

pagesToVisit.push(URL_SEED);
crawl();


//pegar href vs a

function crawl() {
  if(numPagesVisited >= MAX_PAGES_TO_VISIT) {
    console.log("Limites de páginas que posso visitar atingido (100)");
    return;
  }
  var nextPage = pagesToVisit.pop(); //peq
  if (nextPage in pagesVisited) {  //peq
    // pagina ja visitada
    crawl();
  } else {
    // pagina nao visitada
    visitaPagina(nextPage, crawl);
  }
}

function visitaPagina(url, callback) {
  // Add page to our set
  pagesVisiteu[url] = true;
  numPagesVisited++;  


  console.log("Visitando a página  " + url);
  // Faz requisicao
  request(url, function(error, response, body) {

     console.log("Status code: " + response.statusCode);
     if(response.statusCode !== 200) {
       callback();
       return;
     } else {
        // Parse do body
        var $ = cheerio.load(body);
        coletaLinks($);
     }
  }
}

function coletaLinks($) {

  //var linksRelativos = $("a\[href^='/'\]"); //NAO TA PEGANDO DO JEITO QUE
  var linksRelativos = $("a\[href^='/'\]");

  console.log("Achei " + linksRelativos.length + " links relativos nessa página");


  linksRelativos.each(function() {
    pagesToVisit.push(baseUrl + $(this).attr('href'));
  });


  console.log("\n\nPAGES TO VISIT = " + pagesToVisit + "\n\n");


  var key = []; 
  for (key in linksRelativos) {
    if(linksRelativos.hasOwnProperty(key)) { //realmente preciso ver essa property?
        console.log(key, linksRelativos\[key\].attribs.href);
      }
    } 



  fs.writeFile('relativos.txt', linksRelativos, function(err) {
    if(err) {
      return console.log(err);
      //throw err;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: What is this `[![` at the very beginning of your code? and this at the end `][1]][1]`?

Comment: stack's text area added this...

Comment: They won't add those for a plain text area with code in it.  You must have selected some text and tried to tag it with a link or an image.  Please edit to correct as those don't belong in the code area at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why your linter isn't complaining, but you **are** missing a closing bracket in the `request` call inside `visitaPagina`. Second line from the bottom:

```
function visitaPagina(url, callback) {
    // Add page to our set
    pagesVisited[url] = true;
    numPagesVisited++;  


    console.log("Visitando a página  " + url);
    // Faz requisicao
    request(url, function(error, response, body) {

        console.log("Status code: " + response.statusCode);
        if(response.statusCode !== 200) {
            callback();
            return;
        } else {
            // Parse do body
            var $ = cheerio.load(body);
            coletaLinks($);
        }
    } // should be })
}
```

Also, something went wrong with copying the code on SO, you might want to check what's up with that for any future submissions. In this case the screenshots helped, but you should also know that images of code are generally frowned upon on SO.

Good luck!